# Avoiding nested applicative i.e. Applicative f => f (f a)

Tags: haskell, applicative

I have a function:

```
someFun :: Applicative f => f a -> b -> f c
someFun x y = …
```

The argument for `y` that I need to give someFun is an “f b”
Lets say I have values

```
someX :: Applicative f => f a
someY :: Applicative f => f b
```

I tried to do

```
LiftA (someFun someX) someY
```

But that gives me `f (f c)`

I need to result in an `f c`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are asking for is *the* thing that Monads can do but Applicatives *cannot*. With a Monad instance, this is just `join`:

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

What you ask for is impossible, but at least now you have a perfect example of what you can do with a Monad that you can't do with an Applicative.

Comment: That was the thought I was coming to from my reading. I was just making sure I was on the right track.

Comment: ...but it may still be possible with mere `Applicative`s if you can "peer inside" the implementation of `someFun`.

Comment: Are you referring to Lift or is there something else?

Comment: @DanielWagner I don't believe it is. `LiftA` (a.k.a. `fmap`) needs to be replaced with a function `f b -> (b -> f c) -> f c`, but this function is exactly `(>>=)`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs That assumes that we must use `someFun` as-is from outside. If we can change the source code of `someFun` to produce a new function `someFun'`, we may find that we can change the internals in a way that results in a function of type `someFun' :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f c`. It's really impossible to say that this can't be done without seeing the source for `someFun`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I get what you're saying. On the other hand, if we can change the requirements to suit our solution then we can come up with lots of solutions!

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Absolutely! That's why this is a comment, and not an answer: I believe OP asked the wrong question, and I'm just trying to alert him to possible (in fact, I believe *probable*) ways his question may be more flexible than he thinks.